# JavaScript | JSON Objects merge and sort by a value

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json abjects, and I like to merge them into one object and the short the sub-objects based on 'minute' value. Is that posible with JavaScript ?

```
[Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "17"
        Player: "Player A"
        Team: "188564"
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "26"
        Player: "Player B"
        Team: "188564"
        __proto__: Object
    2: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "77"
        Player: "Player A"
        Team: "188564"
        __proto__: Object
[Object, Object]
    0: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "31"
        Player: "Player C"
        Team: "188558"
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "41"
        Player: "Player D"
        Team: "188558"
        __proto__: Object
```

the result I like to be like that:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "17"
        Player: "Player A"
        Team: "188564"
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "26"
        Player: "Player B"
        Team: "188564"
        __proto__: Object
    2: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "31"
        Player: "Player C"
        Team: "188558"
        __proto__: Object
    3: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "41"
        Player: "Player D"
        Team: "188558"
        __proto__: Object
    4: Object
        Live: "188585"
        Minute: "77"
        Player: "Player A"
        Team: "188564"
        __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More then objects they seems arrays of objects. If it's that the case, you can use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to concatenate, and [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort.

Something like:

```
// assuming `aba` is the first array, `cd` the second
var result = aba.concat(cd);

result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.Minute - b.Minute // implicit conversion in number
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your two arrays are already sorted by minute, you can use the "classical" merge algorithms.
If not, you can concat your arrays and sort the result using Array.sort (with a specific compare function).

Edit: here is an example:

1. If arrays are not sorted:

   ```
   var result = array1.concat(array2);
   result.sort(function(item1, item2) {
       return item1.Minute - item2.Minute;
   });
   ```
2. If arrays are sorted, here is a simple merge function:

   ```
   function merge(array1, array2) {
       var results = [];
       var i = 0, j = 0;
       while (i < array1.length && j < array2.length) {
           if (array1[i].Minute <= array2[j].Minute) {
               results.push(array1[i];
               i++;
           }
           else {
               results.push(array2[j];
               j++;
           }
       }
       while (i < array1.length) {
           results.push(array1[i];
           i++;
       }
       while (j < array2.length) {
           results.push(array2[j];
           j++;
       }
       return results;
   }
   ```

Comment: can you provide me with a simple example ?